# Why is my JmenuBar not showing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jmenubar

I'm working on a simple gui.

I can't seem to spot the reason as to why my `JMenuBar` Is not appearing. What am i missing?

Here is the code below.

```
    myMenuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
    myFileMenu = new JMenu("File"); 
    myRegisterItem = new JMenuItem("Register");
    myMenuBar.add(myFileMenu);
    myFileMenu.add(myRegisterItem);
    setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
```

The full class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


public class GUI extends JFrame{


private JTextArea recievedField;
private JButton sendButton;
private JTextField messageField; 
private JComboBox itemComboBox;
private JButton connectButton;
private JTextField userNameField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JButton loginButton;
private JMenuBar myMenuBar;
private JMenu myFileMenu;
private JMenuItem myRegisterItem;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();
}

public GUI() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new MainPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}

public class MainPane extends JPanel {

    public MainPane() {


        myMenuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
        setJMenuBar(myMenuBar); 
        myFileMenu = new JMenu("File"); 
        myRegisterItem = new JMenuItem("Register");
        myMenuBar.add(myFileMenu);
        myFileMenu.add(myRegisterItem);


        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(new LoginPane(), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new ConnectPane(), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(new JScrollPane(recievedField = new JTextArea(5, 20)), gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;

        messageField = new JTextField(10);
        sendButton = new JButton("Send");

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(messageField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(sendButton, gbc);          



    }

}

public class ConnectPane extends JPanel {

    public ConnectPane() {

        itemComboBox = new JComboBox();
        itemComboBox.addItem("Select an Item");
        connectButton = new JButton("Connect");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(itemComboBox, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(connectButton, gbc);
    }

}

public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

    public LoginPane() {

        userNameField = new JTextField(10);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        loginButton = new JButton("Login");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(new JLabel("User name:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(userNameField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(passwordField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        add(loginButton, gbc);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you call `setJMenuBar` on `JPanel` instance this is wrong you should call:

```
frame.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
```

Also no need for:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

as `JFrame` *contentPane* Layout by default is `BorderLayout`

i.e change your code to:

```
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new MainPane());
            frame.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Also do not use `EventQueue` rather `SwingUtilities`:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new MainPane());
            frame.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Dont forget to comment out the `setJmenuBar(..)` in your `MainPane` class:

```
    public MainPane() {
        myMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //notice no call to setJMenuBar

        myFileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        myRegisterItem = new JMenuItem("Register");
        myMenuBar.add(myFileMenu);

        ...
     }
```

Comment: This is a good answer, 1+. I'm surprised that the original poster's code even compiled since JPanel doesn't even have a `setJMenuBar(...)` method. Note that you can add JMenuBars to any container, but if you do that, you must take care to use the right layout managers (usually BorderLayout and added to the NORTH position), and make sure that its container is added correctly to the GUI.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes I was too... But about the (usually `BorderLayout` and added to the NORTH position) I found as long as you add via `setJMenuBar` the position is taken care if (well for default `BorderLayout` atleast

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels funny enough original code compiles (except for missing brace at end of class) I guess one of the components `JPanel` inherits has `setJMenuBar` :O?

Comment: Re this is taken care of via `setJMenuBar(...)`, that's because `setJMenuBar(...)` calls the same menthod in JRootPane which uses a custom layout manager to place the JMenuBar into the root pane's JLayeredPane.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have not set Your JMenuBar Visible.

Add this to your code

```
    frame.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar); // This line to be added
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @DavidKroukamp yes it works without the setVisible also. But what is with the EventQueue Thing and SwingUtilities thing ? Can you please Explain me. I don't have knowledge about it.

Comment: @IshanKhanna regardless its a hack and should not be done that way. EventQueue is awt import `SwingUtilities` is swing import. just feels right IMO, and in most java tutorial including the swing concurrency lesson `SwingUtilities` block is used.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Thank you so much ! It Was a very helpful point that you told me.